# How Can I Pass An Instance Of A Service To A Component Within A Library In Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have a component library that I am building that has multiple shared components what perform various tasks.

I have a new need that is a bit more complex and needs a service provided from the parent application using the component from the library. When I pass that instance of the service to the component library, the only thing that is available within the library component are the properties, no methods are available to be called on the service.

Is there a way to pass a service from a parent component into a child LIBRARY component and have access to the methods on that service. The methods perform multiple HTTP request and would prefer to pass directly into component.

ex.

```
inputSvcParam:any;
construtor(private myClass: MyClass){
 this.inputSvcParam = myClass; // This svc has multiple http request methods as well as static config properties etc.
}

<my-custom-lib-component [internalSvc]="inputSvcParam"></my-custom-lib-component>
```

I log the value of internalSvc within the Library Component and the only values that are actually visible are the properties, no Methods (Therefore no ability to perform HTTP using the Svc).

Does anyone know how I might be able to do this or if I have to build the Svc in my component library and utilize it there?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass service instance as input to the library component. something like below.
`<my-custom-lib-component [service]="myService"></my-custom-lib-component>`

Comment: When I do this, there are no methods available, just properties. how can I make the methods available?